# Is there a concept of limit of formulas

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

I wonder if there is a notion like the limit of formulas (and structures) because I believe it is important in describing countable structures (from finite structures). (For more detail, see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.00581).)  Now I give an excellent example illustrating it. The example is the so-called Quine atom. Let
$$
I_n=\{I_{n-1}\},\quad\text{for } n\geqslant1, \:\text{and } I_0=G_0.
$$
Where $G_0\neq\{G_0\}$. By repeatedly applying the axiom of extensionality, we get
\begin{align}
\phi_n&\iff\exists !\:y_n\in I_n
\\
&\iff \exists !y_n(y_n=I_{n-1})
\\
&\iff\exists !y_n((\exists !y_{n-1}\in y_n)(y_{n-1}\in I_{n-1})\land (\exists !y_{n-1}\in I_{n-1})(y_{n-1}\in y_n))
\\
&\iff\exists !y_n \exists !y_{n-1}(y_{n-1}\in y_n\land y_{n-1}\in I_{n-1})
\\
&\iff\exists !y_n \exists !y_{n-1}(y_{n-1}\in y_n)\land  \exists !y_{n-1}(y_{n-1}=I_{n-2})
\\
&\iff\exists !y_n \exists !y_{n-1}(y_{n-1}\in y_n)\land\exists !y_{n-1}((\exists !y_{n-2}\in y_{n-1})(y_{n-2}\in I_{n-2})\land(\exists !y_{n-2}\in I_{n-2})(y_{n-2}\in y_{n-1}))
\\
&\iff\exists !y_n \exists !y_{n-1}(y_{n-1}\in y_n)\land \exists !y_{n-1}\exists !y_{n-2}(y_{n-2}\in y_{n-1}\land y_{n-2}\in I_{n-2})
\\
&\quad\:\vdots
\\
&\iff \exists !y_n \exists !y_{n-1}(y_{n-1}\in y_n)\land \bigwedge_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n-1}\exists !y_j\exists !y_{j-1}(y_{j-1}\in y_{j})\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{(1)}
\end{align}
Clearly, for any $n<\omega$, $I_{n}\models \phi_n$. This suggests that we can define the limit of formulas as follows.

**Edit:** As pointed out in @Goldstern's example,  formulas for limit can not be too general. So we limit them to a $\aleph_0$-categorical theory.

**Definition 1**: Suppose for any $n<\omega$, $\varphi_{n}$ is in a $\aleph_0$-categorical theory $T$ in $L$ (an infinitary language of $L_{\omega_1, \omega}$) and $M_{n}\models \varphi_{n}$. If for any $n$, there is a $N_n$ that for any $k>N_n,\:M_{k}\models \varphi_{n}$, then $\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}\varphi_{n}$ is a (unique) formula (up to equivalence) in $L$, and $\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}M_{n}$ is a (unique) $L$-structure. Let $\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}\varphi_{n}=\varphi_{\omega}$ and $\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}M_{n}=I_{\omega}$. Then $M_{\omega}\models \varphi_{\omega}$.

Also the follow axioms hold for the limit of formulas.

1. $\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}(\phi_{n}\land\varphi_n)=\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}\phi_{n}\land\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}\varphi_n$
2. $\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}\neg\phi_{n}=\neg\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}\phi_{n}$
3. $\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}\exists x\phi_{n}=\exists x\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}\phi_{n}$
4. $\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}\bigwedge_\limits{1\leqslant j\leqslant n}\phi_j=\bigwedge_\limits{ n<\omega}\phi_n$

We can prove from the above axioms that

5. $\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}(M_{n-1}\in M_n)=\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}M_{n-1}\in \lim_\limits{n\to\omega}M_{n}$
6. $\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}\exists x_n(M_{n-1}\in M_n)=\exists\lim_\limits{n\to\omega} x_n(\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}M_{n-1}\in \lim_\limits{n\to\omega}M_{n})$

(For detailed proofs, see [this paper](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlRd0Qb77Om9bAn0KprNlCzxMWQ?e=q3Mtlj).)

$\operatorname{Th}(I_n)$ is $\aleph_0$-categorical because any $I_i$ can be mapped one-on-one to $I_j$, and so is homogeneous. Since the language of set theory is finite relational, $\operatorname{Th}(I_n)$ is $\aleph_0$-categorical.   By definition 1 and (1), we can see that $\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}\phi_{n}$ and $\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}I_{n}$ both are unique. Let $\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}\phi_{n}=\phi_{\omega}$ and $\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}I_{n}=I_{\omega}$. Then $I_{\omega}\models \varphi_{\omega}$. Furthermore
\begin{align}
\phi_{\omega}&=\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}\phi_{n}
\\
&=\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}\exists !y_n \exists !y_{n-1}(y_{n-1}\in y_n)\land \lim_\limits{n\to\omega}\bigwedge_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n-1}\exists !y_j\exists !y_{j-1}(y_{j-1}\in y_{j})
\\
&=\exists !I_{\omega}(I_{\omega}\in I_{\omega})\land \bigwedge_{n<\omega}\exists !y_n\exists !y_{n-1}(y_{n-1}\in y_{n})\quad\quad\quad(\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}y_n=I_{\omega})
\end{align}

Thus $I_{\omega}=\{I_{\omega}\}$, i.e.  $I_{\omega}$ is  a Quine atom.

Since the limit of formulas (for finite structures) can completely describe the Quine atom, I believe that it (will) play a significant role in the investigation of countable structures. I'd like to confirm that the above notion of limit of formulas and reasoning are not available in current model theory and so belong to a new field of research.

**Edit:** Next I will give two examples on how to apply the limit of formulas to studying some known results in model theory.

**Example 1:** There is arbitrary large number in nonstandard number theory.

Let $\phi_n=\exists x\bigwedge_\limits{m\leqslant n}(x>m)$ and $M_n\models \phi_n$. Since for any $k>n, \:x>k\to x>n, \:M_k\models \phi_n$. So the limit of $\phi_n$ exists and
$$
\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}\exists x\bigwedge_\limits{m\leqslant n}(x>m)=\exists x\bigwedge_\limits{n<\omega}(x>n)
$$
And there is a $M\models \exists x\bigwedge_\limits{n<\omega}(x>n)$.

The second example shows that theory of DLO without endpoints is the limit of union of integers shifts.

**Example 2:** Suppose $T$ is the theory of DLO without endpoints and $M_n=\bigcup_\limits{1\leqslant j<n}(\Bbb{Z}+j/n)$. Then $\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}\bigcup_\limits{n<\omega}M_n=\Bbb{Q}$ and $T = Th(\Bbb{Q})$.

Suppose $\varphi_n,\phi_n,\delta_n$ are sentences specifying the properties of linear ordering, a dense subset and set without endpoints for $M_n$. Then

\begin{align}
\varphi_n &= (∀x,y,z∈M_n)(x≤x∧(x≤y∧y≤x⇒x=y)∧(x≤y∧y≤z⇒x≤z))
\\
\phi_n &= (∀x,y∈M_n)(x<y⇒(∃z∈M_{l})(l>n∧x<z<y))
\\
\delta_n &= (∀x∈M_n)((∃y∈M_n)(y<x)∧(∃y∈M_{n})(x<y))
\end{align}
For any $x,y∈M_{n}\:(x<y)$, set $N_{n}=2n$. Then $∀k>N_{n},\:∃z∈M_{k}$ that $x<z<y$, i.e. $M_{k}\models φ_{n}$. Since $ℤ\modelsϕ_{n}∧δ_{n},\:M_{k}\models ϕ_{n}∧φ_{n}∧δ_{n}$ and $T$ is $ℵ_0$-categorical, $\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}M_n$ is unique. And
\begin{align}
\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}ϕ_{n} &=(∀x,y,z∈\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}M_n)(x≤x∧(x≤y∧y≤x⇒x=y)∧(x≤y∧y≤z⇒x≤z))
\\
\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}\phi_{n} &=(∀x,y∈\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}M_n)(x<y⇒(∃z∈\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}M_n)(x<z<y))
\\
\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}δ_{n} &=(∀x∈\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}M_n)((∃y∈\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}M_n)(y<x)∧(∃y∈\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}M_n)(x<y))
\end{align}
Since $\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}ϕ_{n},\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}φ_{n}, \lim_\limits{n\to\omega}δ_{n}$ are axioms of $Th(\Bbb{Q}),\: \lim_\limits{n\to\omega}M_n=\Bbb{Q}$ and $T = Th(\Bbb{Q})$.

Comment: Your "Definition 1" does not define what "$\lim_n \varphi_n$" is, it just claims that this limit has a certain property.  Please clarify.

Comment: Instead of taking the limit of formulas, would you be interested in taking a limit (indeed, liminf) of the theories of the structures as $\displaystyle \bigcup_{k \geq 1 } \bigcap_{n \geq k} Th(\mathcal{M}_n)$? This seems to be close to what you want.

Comment: What is the motivation for axiom 3: $\lim\limits_{n\to\omega} \exists x\phi_n(x) = \exists x \lim\limits_{n\to\omega} \phi_n(x)$?

Comment: @François G. Dorais, it is used to prove $\lim_\limits{n\to\omega}\exists !y_n \exists !y_{n-1}(y_{n-1}\in y_n)=\exists !I_{\omega}(I_{\omega}\in I_{\omega})$

Comment: @hermes I don't follow why you think it is virtually impossible or too complicated: If your "limit" existence condition is satisfied for a sequence $(\varphi_i: i \in \omega)$, then $\{\varphi_i: i \in \omega\} \subseteq \bigcup_{k \geq 1} \bigcap_{n \geq k} Th(M_n)$. Conversely, any sequence obtained from formulas in $\bigcup_{k \geq 1} \bigcap_{n \geq k} Th(M_n)$ will automatically satisfy your limit existence condition.

Comment: @Burak, yes, it is working as an alternative. So this shows that the limit of formulas is analogous to the limit of a sequence in analysis.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by $G_0$.   If you mean an element $x$ satisfying $x=\{x\}$, then in your example you have $I_0 = \{I_0\} = I_1 = I_2 = \cdots$. But then you are looking at the limit of a constant sequence, which really gives no insight into what you mean by "limit".

Comment: @hermes If you don't give a definition of "limit of a sequence of formulas", your question might be closed as "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: @Goldstern, limit of a sequence of formulas is a (unique) formula. I modified definition 1. Also $G_0≠\{G_0\}$

Comment: What you wrote makes less sense now. What does it mean to be a formula of a theory? To be a consequence of the theory, or to be a formula in the language of the theory? Since you want to have models of the formulas $\varphi_n$, it seems you mean the former. But then you have problems with the definition of limits involving negation.

Comment: It should be a formula of a $\aleph_0$-categorical theory which is $L_{\omega_1, \omega}$ because it has a unique countable model. The definition of negation is consistent with that of general model theory, i.e. $M\models \neg \phi$ iff $M\nvDash \phi$. The limit of formulas is natural because an infinitary formula can be form from a sequence of finite formulas through the limit operation.

Comment: I add two examples to show how to apply the limit of formulas to studying some current results in model theory. This method needs be tested on more works to demonstrate its validity and power.

Comment: Your use of standard notation is so *peculiar* that it is almost impossible to tell what you are saying.

Comment: Here I assume that  an infinitary formula can be formed from a sequence of finitary formulas through the limit operation. It could be a new feature.

Comment: @hermes Saying that your paper is “available upon request” is a bit odd, like you want someone to beg you for it — if the paper is relevant to the question, it’s customary to simply post the arxiv link somewhere in the body. Then inquiring minds can simply click the link to check out your paper if they desire, rather than having to waste time asking for a copy and waiting for a reply. (not a downvoter or upvoter yet here, just mildly interested and following along. if experts in the field agree that it’s a well-posed question i’ll upvote, and they could decide more quickly with a link)

Comment: @Alec Rhea, the file is available now, just click the link in the post.

Comment: One could ask if there are natural interesting compactifications of the set of formulas. For instance, given a structure $M$ one can map a formula $f(x)$ to the set of $t\in M$ such $f(t)$ is true. This gives a compactification (for each $M$). Also given a family $(M_i)$ of structures, one can map a sentence $F$ to the set of $i$ such that $M_i$ satisfies $F$.

Comment: @There is a natural compactification of the set of formulas (over some fixed set of variables) in first-order logic. It's the collection of partial types (i.e. closed subsets of type space) with the Vietoris topology.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not sure which set-theoretic axioms you want to use. Certainly not foundation, but I guess that at least the singleton axiom is allowed.

Consider $M_0:= \{x\}$, where $x$ is any element satisfying $x\not=\{x\}$.  $M_{n+1}:=\{M_n\}$.
Let   $\varphi_n$ be $\phi_n \wedge \psi$, where $\phi_n$ is  your formula, and
$\psi$ says the unique element   is not an element of itself.   Then by your arguments the limit $M_\omega$ must satisfy $M_\omega = \{M_\omega\}$, but it must also satisfy $\psi$, which is a contradiction.

So your axioms and rules lead to a proof of $x=\{x\}$ for all $x$.

It may be that I missed something.  As a matter of fact, I am only guessing at what formal language you are using.

Comment: @ Goldstern, thanks. This example is right which means that formulas for limit can not be too general. So I modified definition 1 to limit them to a $\aleph_0$-categorical theory, which is atomic and exists a complete formula. Since $\psi$ in your example does not follow from the complete formula, the problem is avoided.

Comment: The structures $M_i$ in my example all have exactly one element, so their theory is $\aleph_0$-categorical (in the first order sense). The limit of my formulas is (following your rules) $\phi_\omega\wedge \psi$.

Comment: Your structure is the same as $I_n$. Since $Th(I_n)$ is $ℵ_0$-categorical, it is atomic and has a complete formula  $ϕ_ω$. If $ψ=∃x(x≠\{x\})$, then $ϕ_ω∧ψ$ has no contradiction. However, if $ψ=∀x(x≠\{x\})$, then $ψ∉Th(I_n)$ because $ϕ_ω→¬ψ$.

Comment: The formal language used here is the infinitary language of set theory ($L'_{\omega_1,\omega}$). However, it can be extended to a general language of $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$.

Comment: Also the axioms of this set theory is basically ZF minus the axiom of regularity, where the axiom of extensionality in ZF needs be modified to accommodate NWF sets like Quine atoms. The axiom of union needs change too. The axiom of regularity is dropped and replaced by a new axiom stating that there are NWF sets. The rest axioms (pairing, power set, infinity, replacement, separation) remain the same as those of ZF. See the file listed in the post for more details.

Comment: I have prepared for counter-examples for the limit of formulas, but I can not find them. This allows me to improve the limit of formulas. So I accept this answer.